# highcharts datalabel dynamic rotation as column height

Tags: highcharts

As you can see in the picture each column is accompanied by its datalabels, all is well. The detail is when small amounts and their datalabels is misconfigured with the categories, as seen in the picture (Red square). What I want to do is check if your height is less, to change its rotation from -90 to 0 (Green letters)

See picture of the solution (HighCharts) here:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B93NeaQX1VjUMldzcGIxNnBqaWc/edit

See code JSFiddle of my solution (HighCharts) here :

http://jsfiddle.net/bryan376/325dev4h/1/

This is my code push of series:

```
   options.series.push({
            name: 'Vendedor',
            data: arrFinal,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: -90, //Validation height < 70 "rotation=0" else rotation=-90
                color: 'black',
                align: 'right',
                x: 4,
                y: 10,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '11px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        });
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }
```

Greetings

Comment: Sorry, but if you change rotation from -90 to 0, then dataLabel won't be rotated, not translated in some magic place. I guess you are using old version of Highcharts, since this should be working with overflow. Could you recreate issue on jsfiddle instead of some picture?

Comment: @PawełFus, here's me **JSFiddle**:
http://jsfiddle.net/bryan376/325dev4h/1/
The problem that I have is the conflict between the x axis and datalabel

Comment: The problem is that you set `align: 'right'`, which sets align to the top border of the column. Workaround will be to set `minPointLength`: http://jsfiddle.net/325dev4h/4/ or use `yAxis.type = 'logarithmic'`: http://jsfiddle.net/325dev4h/6/

Comment: @BryanVivanco : Were you able to achieve what you wanted? If yes, can u share?

Comment: @SaadFarooq Yes, the correct answer below this line, by Raein. You can try modifying http://jsfiddle.net/bryan376/325dev4h/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change `Highcharts.Series.prototype.drawDataLabels`, the function to draw the `dataLabels`:

```
Highcharts.Series.prototype.drawDataLabels = (function (func) {
    return function () {
        func.apply(this, arguments);
        if (this.options.dataLabels.enabled || this._hasPointLabels) realignLabels(this);
    };
}(Highcharts.Series.prototype.drawDataLabels));
```

`realignLabels` would be the function to check for the shorter columns, and in it change the `rotation`, `x` and `y` of that specific `dataLabel`:

```
function realignLabels(serie) {

    $.each(serie.points, function (j, point) {
        if (!point.dataLabel) return true;

        var max = serie.yAxis.max,
            labely = point.dataLabel.attr('y'),
            labelx = point.dataLabel.attr('x');

            if (point.y / max < 0.05) {
                point.dataLabel.attr({
                    y: labely - 20,
                    x: labelx + 5,
                    rotation: 0
                });
            }
    });
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/325dev4h/7