# Change Datalabel Color, Rotation and Align values based on Column value in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Possible duplicate of Unsolved [highcharts datalabel dynamic rotation as column height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391962/highcharts-datalabel-dynamic-rotation-as-column-height)

The Fiddle for a sample column chart : http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/266/

There are some very large columns, and one very small column. I want to show white labels vertically rotated to -90 degrees in the large columns, and for smaller columns, I want to display dark gray labels on the top of the column, with 0 degree rotation.

After some messing up, I have achieved this : http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/267/
I can change the color of the label based on the value in the formatter function, but using global variables to get the align and rotation right are not working.

Any help in this regard would be very helpful. I cannot use the solutions suggested in the duplicate question, as I need to keep the Y axis uniform and cannot set MinPointLength.

Final Code:

```
var GlobalRotation = -90;
var GlobalAlign = 'right';
var X;
var Y;
$(function () {
 $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        height: 700
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0.2,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                inside: false,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                formatter: function() {
                    var max = this.series.yAxis.max,
                        color =  this.y / max < 0.05 ? 'black' : 'white';
                        //GlobalRotation = this.y / max < 0.05 ? 0 : -90;
                        //GlobalAlign = this.y / max < 0.05 ? 'left' : 'right';
                        //X = this.y / max < 0.05 ? 4 : 4;
                        //Y = this.y / max < 0.05 ? 0 : 5;
                    return '<span style="color: ' + color + '">' + this.y + ' </span>';   
                },
                verticalAlign: "top",
                rotation : GlobalRotation,
                align: GlobalAlign
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 2.33]
    }]
    });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change `Highcharts.Series.prototype.drawDataLabels`, the function to draw the `dataLabels`:

```
Highcharts.Series.prototype.drawDataLabels = (function (func) {
    return function () {
        func.apply(this, arguments);
        if (this.options.dataLabels.enabled || this._hasPointLabels) realignLabels(this);
    };
}(Highcharts.Series.prototype.drawDataLabels));
```

`realignLabels` would be the function to check for the shorter columns, and in it change the `rotation`, `x` and `y` of that specific `dataLabel`:

```
function realignLabels(serie) {

    $.each(serie.points, function (j, point) {
        if (!point.dataLabel) return true;

        var max = serie.yAxis.max,
            labely = point.dataLabel.attr('y'),
            labelx = point.dataLabel.attr('x');

            if (point.y / max < 0.05) {
                point.dataLabel.attr({
                    y: labely - 20,
                    x: labelx + 5,
                    rotation: 0
                });
            }
    });
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/270/

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works perfectly as I wanted. I want a little more control over the styling of the labels, can we also assign color in the realignlabels method? I tried it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/271/ but it doesn't works. Also can u guide me to any docs which can help me more with this types of modifications?

Comment: You can change the `style` like this: `style: 'font-weight:bold;fill:#F00;'`. The `fill` element is the one you want to change: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/272/

Comment: As for the guide, I don't know any. I just tested and saw the results, it is based mostly on experience. For example for the `color` you asked I used `console.log` to check the attributes of `dataLabel` and finally figured the element you are looking for is `fill`. You can also search, it is a very good help in these cases.